# Rank diagrams of permutations $w \in S_{m}$ in the study of complete flag varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, flag-varieties, schubert-calculus

I'm looking for some good references that may either prove or help to prove the following statement: Show that a matrix $r=(r_{pq})_{1 \leq p,q \leq m}$ defines a rank diagram for some pair of complete flags in $\mathbb{C}^m$ iff $\exists$ a permutation $w \in S_m$ such that $$r_{pq}= \text{#} \{(i,j): i \leq p, w(i)=j \leq q\} \text{,}$$ i.e., the number of pairs $(i, j)$ with the given above property. A rank diagram $D(w)$ of a permutation $w \in S_{m}$ consists of the pairs $(i,j)$ of integers $1$ through $m$ such that $j \leq w(i)$ and $i \leq w^{-1}(j)$. I'm trying to think if there is a direction in the proof that can be trivially shown, but I'm not so sure about that. How should I begin with the proof?

Comment: For the first, you're going to need to state a definition of "rank diagram". For the second, you presumably want to say "$dim()$" _equals something_. In any case, any results of this sort are going to follow from the Bruhat decomposition, see e.g. Fulton's "Young Tableaux".

Comment: The question has been edited for clarity.

Comment: Instead of "some pair of flags", use the $GL(n)$-action to turn one flag into the base flag, the other into $w\cdot$ the base flag for some $w\in S_n$. That this is achievable (and $w$ is unique) is the Bruhat decomposition.

Comment: A useful reference I found is "Flags, Schubert Polynomials, Degeneracy Loci, and Determinantal Formulas" also by Fulton. The Bruhat decomposition is mentioned there as well, I think.